# R: How to increase the pixel size (decrease the spatial resolution) of a satellite image by applying a Gaussian filter with a (large) width

Tags: r, raster, resolution, gaussian

**The goal**

I am trying to simulate coarse data *as though they were measured with a coarse PSF* (point spread function).

**The data**

I have a satellite image with 15m pixel size and I want to convolve it with a Gaussian kernel to reduce the spatial resolution at 460m. To do this I need to apply a transfer function (TF; e.g., Gaussian) to the fine data, but with a very large width. This produces the coarse data.

Is there any function that takes as input a fine resolution image, applies a Gaussian TF and produces a coarse spatial resolution image?

To make my problem even more clear, I am following the paper '*The effect of the point spread function on downscaling continua*'. All in all, the authors wanted to downscale a coarse satellite image using an ancillary fine spatial resolution variable. The downscaling consists of two steps:

1. regression
2. kriging on regressions residuals

During the regression, they had to upscale the fine resolution image to match the pixel size of the coarse resolution image and then they performed the regression. This upscaling **had to be done using the PSF**.

From [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18_1Kshb8WbT04gwOw4d_xhfQenULDXdB?usp=sharing) you can download my image.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423291/how-can-i-both-resample-and-aggregate-a-raster-using-terra) in `terra`.

Comment: @Chris I don't think that's the solution. I just tried it and the result doesn't look right. The resulting raster has very strange values (0-93) and some stripes all over it. Unfortunately I can't post an image of how it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(terra)

wd = "path/"

ntl = rast(paste0(wd, "ntl.tif")) # coarse res raster
pop = rast(paste0(wd, "pop.tif")) # fine res raster

for (i in seq(from = 0.2, to = 0.8, by = 0.2)) {
  
  print(i)
  
  gf <- focalMat(pop, i*res(ntl), "Gauss") 
  r_gf <- focal(pop, w = gf, na.rm = TRUE)

  r_gf = aggregate(r_gf, fact = 4, fun = "mean", cores = 3)
  
  r_gf <- crop(r_gf, ext(s))
  r_gf <- mask(r_gf, s)
  
  stringedi = gsub("\\.", "", toString(format(i, nsmall = 2)))
  
  writeRaster(r_gf, 
              paste0("path/pop", 
                     stringedi, ".tif"), 
              overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

The above code, first applies a Gaussian filter to the fine res raster (*pop*), then aggregates the raster to match the spatial resolution of the coarse resolution raster (*ntl*), then clips the aggregated raster and finally it export it.